# How some android phone supports 4k video capture and playback while some pc doesn't.?

Tags: video, processor

I just heard of the Snapdragon 805 specs and i was astonished to see that it supports 4K Video capture and playback, then came to know that some Sony Smartphones already supports 4K Video capture and playback and it has it the market already.

My PC, an Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 with 6GB DDR3 RAM and an NVIDIA 9500GT 1GB DDR2  doesn't support 4K Video playback (captured in RED).

Does it mean that those Smartphones that does support 4K Video playback is actually faster and more efficient than my PC if not, how do they do that.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most smartphones have dedicated video encode and decode hardware. It's specifically designed for that task, and it has a fast connection to the memory, and often the decoded video frames can be accessed directly by the compositor hardware so they don't have to be copied (or *blitted*) into the framebuffer. You wouldn't be surprised that a handheld digital video camera can do 4k video capture: it's specifically designed for that purpose. Your smartphone works the same way.

Most PCs don't have this special hardware, so they have to do video encode and decode with software, on the CPU, or with a special *compute shader* on the GPU. Either way, that's always going to be slower and less power-efficient than having special-purpose hardware.

Comment: Update on PC requirements: Intel's Haswell CPUs with integrated graphics should be fine for 4k playback. Here are some links:
* [GoPro min. system requirements](https://gopro.com/support/articles/minimum-system-requirements-for-4k-editing-and-playback)
* [Ars Technica user tests](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1252691)

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Dan_Hulme 's answer, think about it in terms of use cases.

Video/still capture on a mobile device has become a huge feature for many users, and a huge selling point for manufacturers.

Considering the (relative to 1080p) lack of 4K content out there, the chance that a PC user will want to play a 4k video on their PC is fairly low.

Due to the camera-hardware arms race on the mobile market (see link in comments, since apparently you can't post more than 2 links w/o 10+ rep), it very likely that a user will want to *capture* a 4k video on a mobile device, and if a user is capturing 4k video on a device, they will certainly want to view the video in 4k, right on their device.

Let's also look at your machine. Your machine is what I would consider low-to-mid-range. It has a budget quad-core processor with a dedicated Nvidia video card and a decent amount of RAM. High-end video fidelity was clearly not on the manufacturer's priority list.

All of this above explains *why* your PC might not support 4K while your phone might, and @Dan_Hulme above explains how they are able to support 4K, but is your smartphone more powerful than your PC? No. Probably not.

As the benchmarks in a reply on this thread shows (link in comment, you don't have to scroll down very far). Even a Core 2 Duo Dual-Core beats an iPhone 5s. Not to mention a top-of-the-line consumer CPU like the i7 Quad-Core.

And as this article shows (Link in comments), chances are, your phone can't actually compete with today's video card, although it might be able to give an 05-07 card a run for its money.

TL;DR: No, your phone isn't faster than your PC.

Comment: Camera hardware (first missing link): http://videos.venturebeat.com/samsung-eyes-20-megapixels-as-camera-arms-race-heats-up-518033588

Comment: CPU benchmarks (second missing link): http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1858266/apple-desktop-cpu.html

Comment: GPU benchmarks (last missing link): http://www.anandtech.com/show/6877/the-great-equalizer-part-3/2